# any way to set screen options wordpress via the database?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-503

My products woocommerce page will not load because it is set to show 100 products at the time. (server 503 error because of server overload). Is there any way to set this value of 100 back to a lower number via the mysql database of wordpress directly?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you referring to the admin product dashboard page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `wp_usermeta` table there is a row per user that sets this limit.  Look for the `meta_key ='edit_product_per_page'` and set the `meta_value = 20` which is the default.  You can update it using phpMyAdmin and manually edit the row.

Comment: Fantastic. That did the trick. Thank you! Marked as accepted answer.

Comment: Perfect! This solution is still working in the year 2021. Thank you! It helped me a lot and took away a lot of problems ....

Comment: Still works in 2022. The table name is 'wp_usermeta' though.